# Seeing Attachments from File Geodatabase at ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, relationship-class, attachments

I have a feature class (Buildings) related to a table in a file geodatabase (Assets) (1-M RC). The Assets table has attachments of its own (PDFs): mean it has another table in RC with blob data that contain the PDFs.

The Building feature class is in a feature dataset and both relationship classes are in the feature dataset.

[image]

I have tried to publish the GDB a few ways (As A full GDB and as a feature service) into AGOL but I can't see the PDFs Attachments. Though I can see my related assets rows while pop-uping the feature's layer entities, I can not  further related it to the attachment table and its contents.

I made sure that the table has its attachments enabled through the REST platform.
[image]

My question is this:
1. How to see my PDF's using pop-ups interface in AGOL when interacting with the feature layer (Buildings)?
2. Alternatively, how to open attachments that is related to a stand-alone table in AGOL?

Further question:
1. Where does the attachments table is saved in the AGOL server? Why can't I see it?

Comment: It is known limitation, you cannot see attachments to related table in agol. Funny thing they are visible, etc in collector

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.